# How to remove built-in errorlist of Django model forms?

Tags: python, django

I made a model form in Django that enables user to create an instance of that model. All is well save one thing. Built-in error lists of Django is annoying. I want those errors to show itself when user actually made that error. When I open my page it looks like this
[image]

Please help me how do I remove these errorlist temporarily so that when user left input fields empty. It pop ups itself?

I don't know if you need these codes to solve this problem, but here it is:
views.py file here

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def article_create(request):
    article_form = ArticleForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
    if article_form.is_valid():
        instance = article_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.author = request.user
        article_form.save()
    return render(request, 'blog/article-create.html', {'form': article_form})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `request.POST or None` idiom - which I dislike, but never mind - for the data parameter, but not for the files parameter. Since you pass an (empty) dict for the files, Django takes your form as bound, and therefore tries to validate it.

If you insist on using this idiom, you need to do it for both:

```
article_form = ArticleForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
```

But really, it's much more Pythonic to be explicit:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    article_form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if article_form.is_valid():
        instance = article_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.author = request.user
        article_form.save()
        return redirect('/')
else:
    article_form = ArticleForm()
return render(request, 'blog/article-create.html', {'form': article_form})
```

Note, you always need to redirect after a successful POST, as I have done above.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, you have helped me a lot in previous questions as well. Hope I could become like you once. God bless you and thank you sir!
One question: why you dislike request.post or None. 
Do you prefer using if method.request == 'post' this one!

Comment: As I say in the answer, I think it's more explicit to do it this way, and therefore more in line with the spirit of Python.